# Test for continuity of $f(x,y)=\frac{x+ye^{-x^2}}{1+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Test for continuity of $f(x,y)=\frac{x+ye^{-x^2}}{1+y^2}$

I tried using polar coordinates but not able to see it is discontinuous. How to confirm? Any hint?

Comment: Where would the discontinuity be?

Answer (score 2):

Note: The denominator has no zeros in the reals. Thus, you have a form 
$$
\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}
$$
$g$ and $h$ continuous everywhere and $h$ never zero. You may evaluate limits by substitution i.e. your function is everywhere continuous.